# Is there a way to have Backblaze exclude .svn folders?

Tags: backup

As a developer, I have almost all of my project in Subversion and check them out using TortoiseSVN/Subversion which create a folder named .svn inside every checked out folder.

I'm wondering if there is a way to tell Backblaze to skip backing up all .svn folders?

Comment: You probably already know this, but I thought I would point it out anyway: If you don't back up your SVN files / folders as well, you will lose your project history, branch, etc. information.

Comment: Yeah, I have all of that in the SVN which is backed up separately. I only need this backup for the stuff that isn't in the SVN already. I don't believe those .svn folders contain the actual history anyway. That's contained on the server.

Comment: Josh is right: if you want to restore your backup because some files were not in SVN yet, then why not make life easy and restore the local SVN status information (the .svn folders) as well? Without that: how to tell which files were not in SVN yet? (Alternatively: just don't backup your project workspaces at all.)

Comment: Option 1: TortoiseSVN does a really good job of checking out over an existing folder structure without the .svn folders. Option 2: check out to a separate folder with TortoiseSVN and then copy the backup into that folder. Really quite simple.

Comment: i've found googling [a solution for windows](https://aoeex.com/phile/backblaze-custom-exclusions/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The current GUI only allows the exclusion of individual folders, not all folders called e.g. .svn

But there is an advanced way of adding exclusions - see

https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/220973007-Advanced-Topic-Setting-Custom-Exclusions-via-XML

As an example, I added the following rule to exclude .git hidden folders, *only* if they were in my ~/Sites folder (another similar could apply to .svn, node_modules etc.):

```
<excludefname_rule plat="mac" osVers="*"  ruleIsOptional="t" skipFirstCharThenStartsWith="users/" contains_1="/sites/" contains_2="/.git/" doesNotContain="*" endsWith="*" hasFileExtension="*" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change which folders and files are excluded from the backup, by clicking on the **Settings…** button on the Backblaze Control Panel and selecting the **Exclusions** tab.

Comment: Just FYI, in the new interface the tab is called "Exclude from Backup". To exclude a folder you include it in the list of "file types".

Comment: So adding `.svn` or `.git` as a file type will exclude all folders by that name?

Comment: @NicholasTolleyCottrell apparently it only works with "file types", i.e. extensions. It doesn't work for `.git` as they are folders: https://twitter.com/backblaze/status/303407239098671104

Comment: Use Command+Shift+Period to show hidden files in the file dialog on Mac. http://osxdaily.com/2011/03/01/show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x-dialog-boxes-with-commandshiftperiod/

Answer (score 0):

Add `svn` in the exclusion list, which you can find in the preferences:

[image]